# Google Custom Search Foundation 5 Zurb Display Issue

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, google-custom-search

I am using the foundation 5 by Zurb and have display issue regarding Google Custom Search Engine. Searched The whole internet but don't find any clue. Can Anybody Please Help?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your google search box css:

```
    background-image: inherit;
    box-sizing: content-box;
```

Comment: Both the search button and the modal pop-up are impacted. Which class are you proposing to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS file.

```
.gsc-control-cse  * {
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !importantx;
 box-sizing:  content-box !important;
}

.gsc-control-cse input {
 box-shadow: none !important;
}

.gsc-control-cse input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.gsc-control-cse table {
 border: none;
 background: transparent;
}

.gsc-input-box, .gsc-search-box .gsc-input>input, .gsc-input-box-hover {
 -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Credit goes to [Manny](http://programming.mvergel.com/2013/07/solved-zurb-foundation-and-google.html#.VZLujfnBzRY).